# sqlite выбрать 10 наибольших значений в группе из одной таблицы

Tags: sql, sqlite

Имеется таблица состоящая из 3х столбцов: classname, word, coeff. Нужно выбрать по 10 записей для каждого класса с максимальными значениями коэффициента. Как это можно сделать в SQLite? Заранее благодарен

Comment: Используйте ключевое слово [LIMIT](http://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-limit/).

Comment: А для получения максимальных значений сортируйте `order by desc`.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, `select * from table order by coeff desc limit 10` возвращает всего 10 записей с максимальными коэффициентами, а не 10 наибольших из каждого класса

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если у вашей таблицы (в примере "test") есть уникальный ID, то можно так:

```sql
select * from test a where a.id in (
  select id from test b where b.classname = a.classname
  order by b.coeff desc limit 10
);
```

Если уникального ключа нет, можете его "создать" через что-то типа

```
a.classname || '/' || a.word || '/' || a.coeff
```

Либо использовать `rowid`.

Источник: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28119350/1892060.